# sum of factors of a given number

Tags: python, sum

i have written this  code which finds factors of a number .after thinking and trying so much i could not get the sum of the numbers I get in output.I wish to get the sum of these numbers as output recursively.here's my code:

```
def p(n,c):
    s = 0
    if c >= n:
        return n
    if n % c == 0:
        s += c
        print(s,end=',')
    return p(n,c+1)
n = int(input('enter no:'))
c = 1
print(p(n,c))
```

Comment: `s` is a local variable of the function `p(n,c)` so it will be reset each time you call the function recursively.

Comment: if i make it global i am still  getting lot of numbers but i just need the sum.for example if n =24,then i should get 36 but i am getting 1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain why you expect to get 36... If you go with just the prime factors only (24 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3), the sum would be 9 (or 5 if you ignore duplicates). If you include 4, 6, 8, and 12 in the list, the sum would be 39 (35 ignoring duplicates). Also including 1 and 24, which are technically both factors of 24, the sum jumps to 64 or 60. None of those is 36, though...

Comment: i expect to get the sum:1+2+3+4+6+8+12=36 as this is the value of s befor c>=n condition is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the comments, it appears that this might be what you want:

```
sum([n for n in xrange(1,24) if 24 % n == 0])
```

To make it a bit more generic:

```
def sum_of_factors(x):
  return sum([n for n in xrange(1,x) if x % n == 0])
```

EDIT: here's a recursive version:

```
def sum_of_factors(x, y=1):
  if (y >= x):
    return 0
  if (x % y == 0):
    return y + sum_of_factors(x, y + 1)
  return sum_of_factors(x, y + 1)

>>> sum_of_factors(24)
36
```

Comment: thanks,but i wish to find it without using for/while loops. i can only  use recursion.

Comment: i need another help.how can i do it in O(√n)?

Comment: no it's not homework but some practice questions before a minor exam.

Comment: You can do it in `O(sqrt(n))` by only iterating/recursing over numbers up to `sqrt(n)`, and adding both `y` and `x/y` whenever you find a `y` that divides `x`. I think that'll probably really only gain you something for really large numbers... Also, that'll likely give you the answer of 60 instead of 36, unless you put a couple extra tests in...

Answer (score 0):

Is this the output you are looking for?
Use global variable,

```
s = 0 
def p(n,c):
   global s
   if c >= n:
      return n
   if n % c == 0:
      s += c
      print(s,end=',')
   return p(n,c+1) 
n = int(input('enter no:')) 
c = 1 
print(p(n,c))
```

Output

```
enter no:1,3,6,10,16,24,36,24
```

Comment: i just want the 36 which is the sum of all the factors excluding number or i can also stay with 60 i.e 36 +24(number itself).